# How to convert AVI to MP4 using FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this script to convert an avi file into a mp4 file

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi video.mp4
```

The resulting file I got is encoded using H264 but the video is flawed.

What am I doing wrong? I would like the resulting video to be encoded a good codec that is widely spread.

- This is the [source AVI file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/z4xe92khk16x57t/Counter-AVI.avi) (5 MB)
- This is the [resulting MP4 file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/jiuwj1klm6l66z0/Counter-MP4.mp4) (20 KB)

Does this defect have a name? Also I can't upload the video on Twitter, why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use ffmpeg to transform mp4 to same high-quality avi file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83161/use-ffmpeg-to-transform-mp4-to-same-high-quality-avi-file).  Opposite direction but the process is the same.  `ffmpeg` has a lot of different options for various tasks. When in doubt, consult the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html)

Comment: Input and output files look ok to me, perhaps try a more embellished command line: `ffmpeg -i Counter-AVI.avi -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 16 test.mp4`

Answer (score 4):

MPEG-4 is still currently the most universally compatible and widespread codec, Instead of using H.264 codec

Execute:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -c:v mpeg4 video.mp4
```

This will specify "**MPEG-4 Video (Simple Profile)**" codec instead of "**H.264 (High 4:4:4 Profile)**".